# Kinetics of nitric oxide production

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, kinetics

Several articles affirm that NO can enhance the glutamate release from the presynaptic site; moreover, glutamate has been recognized as a major brain neurotransmitter and is considered to mediate excitatory transmission at most synapses of the central nervous system.

First point is the following: is the chemical reaction reported [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_oxide_synthase) the equation that describes how NO is produced? If yes, is there a way to model this reaction in such a way it can be simulated by using MATLAB? And finally, do you know what are the kinetic properties of this reaction?

Comment: I believe NO is nitrous oxide , not nitric oxide ( NO2)

Comment: NO stands for nitric oxide (or equivalently nitrogen monoxide), but nitrous oxide is N2O.

Comment: It's enzymatic reaction, so I guess it probably follows Michaelis-Menten kinetics.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Ah nope, $N_2O$ is *nitrous* oxide (nitrogen in the +1 oxidation state) and $NO$ is *nitric* oxide (nitrogen in the +2 oxidation state). I had trouble wrapping my head around it too, when I was first introduced to those terms ;-)